# Excel pulling multiple wild card data from string to define type in other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard, partial

Wondering if there is a better way to pull multiple partial texts from a string in one column to define a type for each line item in a separate column.

string examples:

- HEAVY HEX BOLT ASME B18.2.1 ASTM A320/A320M GR.B8M CL 2 PL UNC CLASS 2A SIZE: 5/8"" UNC X 2 1/2""  -
- VALVE TURNING DEVICE * MFR STD BRACKET AS PER DATA SHEET NO. : USSP-CBE-00-LT-000-T01-0713  -

my formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*support*"),"SUPPORT",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*pipe*"),"SPOOL/PIPE",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*bolt*"),"BOLT/NUT/WASHER",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*washer*"),"BOLT/NUT/WASHER",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*nut*"),"BOLT/NUT/WASHER",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*valve*"),"FITTING",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,""),"BLANK",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*flange*"),"FITTING",
IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*coupling*"),"ACCESSORIES",no)))))))))
```

I get an error every few hundred rows that says `#NAME?` Even though it works 95% throughout my spreadsheet.

I get an error every few hundred rows that says `#NAME?` Even though it works 95% throughout my spreadsheet. The partial text is valid in the column I'm pulling the data from so it should label the type but it doesn't.

Comment: `no` is not quoted and is giving the error.

Comment: `,IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*bolt*"),"BOLT/NUT/WASHER",IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*washer*"),"BOLT/NUT/WASHER",IF(COUNTIF(W1292,"*nut*"),"BOLT/NUT/WASHER"` can be resumed into one single IF using the operator `OR`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You may benefit from SUMPRODUCT:

```
=IF(A1="";"BLANK";IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$9;SUMPRODUCT(COUNTI(A1;"*"&$D$2:$D$9&"*")*ROW($D$2:$D$9))-1);"NO"))
```

Comment: So now I have some instances where there are two keywords in the same string. How can I make one take priority if both partial strings are in the line item?

Comment: Also if I use SUMPRODUCT wouldn't I have to make a table with the thousands of line item tags to sort the data? The spread sheet has over 2 million line items.

Comment: *I have some instances where there are two keywords in the same string* That's a different question and you should first make sure this solution works and then try to modify it with your needs. *wouldn't I have to make a table with the thousands of line item tags to sort the data?* Yes you should. *The spread sheet has over 2 million line items* if you got 2 million records then Excel **is not** the tool you need because it can handle only around 1 million records. Try designing a database and cross data there.